# using count query in sql

Tags: sql, database

How could I write an SQL that will display authors and a total number of their publications with a sub query included in my SELECT STATEMENT but this is what I have

[image]

Comment: I believe you missed a sentence. Why do you need a subquery here?

Comment: Please don't insert screenshots of code or queries, insert them **as text** into the question and format as code (4 spaces indent)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.auth_name,COUNT( p.pub_title ) AS count_of_publications 
  FROM Author a
LEFT JOIN
       Wrote w
    ON a.auth_id = w.auth_id
LEFT JOIN 
       Publication p
    ON w.pub_id = p.pub_id
GROUP BY a.auth_name;
```